# How to get meaningful position information on UnicodeDecodeError when reading a file line by line in python3

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, text-processing

`UnicodeDecodeError` informs the user about the position of a codepoint that cannot be decoded. However when using other methods that plain `read()` on the file object, this position is meaningless w.r.t. the file due to buffering.

Say I create a file like this

```
#!/usr/env/python3
#coding: utf8

text = 100000* u"abcd\n" + u"ß\n"

with open("/tmp/test.txt", "w", encoding="iso-8859-1") as fi:
    fi.write(text)
```

then `read()` gives the true position

```
open("/tmp/test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 500000: invalid continuation byte
```

while other methods do not

```
open("/tmp/test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines()
# -> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 288: invalid continuation byte
```

The same applies to other reading methods like `for line in <file_obj>` etc.

Is there a paradigmatic approach to obtain a meaningful error message with the original position w.r.t. the file (so that an end user would possibly understand it) without too much boilerplate code or an additional parsing step to detect that position?

---

As a mere side note, when looping over the lines, the exception is not even guaranteed to occur in the same line due to buffering as the following example shows:

```
#!/usr/env/python3
#coding: utf8

with open("/tmp/test.txt", "w", encoding="iso-8859-1") as fi:
    for num in range(100000):
        fi.write(u"valid line {}\n".format(num))
    fi.write(u"ß\n")

try:
    with open("/tmp/test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fi:
        for line in fi:
            pass
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print(line)
    # -> valid line 99920
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you need? You seem to already know that ``.read()`` gives you the file position of the issue – just run ``.read()`` if an error occurs. Is that what you mean by "without ... additional parsing step"? Are you concerned about the duplicate code, or the performance?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry, if that was unclear. I have lots of nontrivial parsing code, and I would like to change it as few as possible, such that a meaningful error à la `read()` reaches the "top" of my architecture. And yes, I am concerned about both the extra code as well as the performance :)